# generate a 12-byte random in Java

Tags: javascript, java, key, endianness, nonce

I was recently asked to do a task as the following:
"We need to generate a key, which has a 12-byte binary value. The key is created by concatenating little-endian 8-byte random number with 4 bytes of zero-padding.
To construct the actual key, one would need to copy little-endian version of the 8-byte number to a string and append four zero bytes."

What would be the best way to do so in JAVA or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> final Random r = new Random();
>
> long value = r.nextLong() >>> -64;   
>
> String Key =Long.toBinaryString(value);
>
>         // pad Key with 32 0s
>
>
>       // output number on file
> ```

**`r.nextLong() >>> -64`** will ensure that you have 8 byte binary number.